# Reading parquet files from S3 with custom endpoint in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, parquet, endpoint

I'm trying to find out the best way to read parquet data from S3 storage.
**First approach**:

```
BasicSessionCredentials cred = new BasicSessionCredentials(key,secret, "");
        AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("custom_endpoint", region))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(cred))
                .build();

        GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest("bucket_name", "relative_path", "");
        S3Object obj = client.getObject(req);
        S3ObjectInputStream cont = obj.getObjectContent();
```

This way I'm able to read the object, but I couldn't find the way of reading parquet data from InputStream

**Second approach**:

```
String SCHEMA_TEMPLATE = "{" +
                        "\"type\": \"record\",\n" +
                        "    \"name\": \"schema\",\n" +
                        "    \"fields\": [\n" +
                        "        {\"name\": \"timeStamp\", \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
                        "        {\"name\": \"temperature\", \"type\": \"double\"},\n" +
                        "        {\"name\": \"pressure\", \"type\": \"double\"}\n" +
                        "    ]" +
                        "}";
String PATH_SCHEMA = "s3a";
Path internalPath = new Path(PATH_SCHEMA, bucketName, folderName);
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(SCHEMA_TEMPLATE);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "key");
configuration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "secret");
configuration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "custom_endpoint");
AvroReadSupport.setRequestedProjection(configuration, schema);
ParquetReader<GenericRecord> = AvroParquetReader.GenericRecord>builder(internalPath).withConf(configuration).build();
GenericRecord genericRecord = parquetReader.read();

while(genericRecord != null) {
        Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
        genericRecord.getSchema().getFields().forEach(field -> valuesMap.put(field.name(), genericRecord.get(field.name()).toString()));

        genericRecord = parquetReader.read();
}
```

But for the second case I'm not able to read data and getting **SocketTimeoutException**.
Help me to find the right approach
Thanks

Comment: So I was able to resolve the issue by adding these configuration settings

configuration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
configuration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider");